# Django: Display form name in template with prefix

Tags: django, forms, templates, prefix

I have looked around for an answer for this for a while now with no success.
I basically want to get the name of a form field with the prefix included. Does anyone know how to do this?

Example:

Let's say I create a form in views.py and include a prefix like this:

```
myform = SomeForm(prefix="prefix")
```

and then pass it to my template. If I then access a form field within the template directly I by {{ myform.username }} get something like this (notice that the prefix was included):

```
<select id="id_prefix-username" name="prefix-username"> ...
```

If I however would like to manually create the form tag and just insert the name, then I don't get the prefix with it:

```
<input name="{{ myform.username.name }}">
```

will generate:

```
<input name="username">
```

Notice how it is now missing the prefix. Now, I can do it like this to achieve the same result:

```
 <input name="{{ myform.prefix }}-{{ myform.username.name }}">
```

But there must be a built in way to do this?

Comment: `{{ myform.prefix }}-{{ myform.username.name }}` looks ok to me.

Comment: Create a custom template tag for it.

Comment: No. There's not a built in way to do this. You'll have to write a custom tag as @dan-klasson said, or just add the prefix manually like you've done.

Answer (score 17):

You can use html_name instead:

```
<input name="{{ myform.username.html_name }}">
```

That should add the prefix as needed