# How to apply form prefix in django template

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I was having a lot of trouble today with having mutiple forms in a page. my problem was having the form action to different url. it was able to different the form, so even the form.errors will know the one to display. i check [here](https://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/), which was where i was go but still didnt tell me how to display these forms in django template after defined them in views.py.

This was my views

```
def TermAdd(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form1 = SchoolFirstTermForm(request.POST, prefix="form1", request=request)
        form2 = SchoolSecondTermForm(request.POST, prefix="form2", request=request)
        form3 = SchoolThirdTermForm(request.POST, prefix="form3", request=request)
        if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid():
            if 'term_add_button' in request.POST:
                myterm = form1.save(commit=False)
                myterm.session = session_dates
                myterm.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, ("Administrator %s, The %s for %s Sessions were added successfully") % (request.user, myterm.name_of_term, session_dates.current_session))
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('school_session.views.SchoolTermAddView'))
    else:
        form1 = SchoolFirstTermForm(prefix="form1")
        form2 = SchoolSecondTermForm(prefix="form2")
        form3 = SchoolThirdTermForm(prefix="form3")
    context = {'form1':form1, 'form2':form2, 'form3':form3, 'session_dates':session_dates, 'term_dates':term_dates}
    return render_to_response('schools/admin_term_add.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Here is models.py

```
class SchoolFirstTerm(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(SchoolSession)
    name_of_term = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of Term", max_length=15, help_text="leave this except you want to change the name of your First Term to another word")
    term_start = models.DateField()
    term_end = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s Term of %d/%d session" % (self.name_of_term, self.session.current_session)

class SchoolSecondTerm(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(SchoolSession)
    name_of_term = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of Term", max_length=15, help_text="leave this except you want to change the name of your First Term to another word")
    term_start = models.DateField()
    term_end = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s Term of %d/%d session" % (self.name_of_term, self.session.current_session)

class SchoolThirdTerm(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(SchoolSession)
    name_of_term = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name of Term", max_length=15, help_text="leave this except you want to change the name of your First Term to another word")
    term_end = models.DateField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s Term of %d/%d session" % (self.name_of_term, self.session.current_session)
```

the three models share the same field, and their forms are to be in the same page, so assuming i have {{ form.name_of_term.errors }}, i didnt know how to add the prefix of form which i displayed in html format `<input type="text" name="form1-name_of_term" id="id_form1-name_of_term" />`

I tried this `{{ form.prefix }}{{ form.name_of_term }}` and also read some answers like [How can I build multiple submit buttons django form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866272/how-can-i-build-multiple-submit-buttons-django-form), [Django: Display form name in template with prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123695/django-display-form-name-in-template-with-prefix). I had some cool answers there but it didnt help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all, I tried this

```
{{ form1.name_of_term }}
```

simply made it work like charm. Although i didnt know and i cant explain. I just taught that since i defined it as `form1`, then i should be able to retrieve the form